# How can I test the equality of two MediaStreams?

Tags: webrtc, mediastream

I'm wondering if there is a way to determine if two [MediaStreams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStream) are *equal*.

#### What do you mean by "equal"?

I'd like to determine if the two streams are using the same hardware sources (Same microphone and camera are being used). 
Acquiring `streamB` with the exact same constraints as `streamA` would mean they are equal.

Here is what I've tried so far:

1. comparing via the MediaStream `id` e.g.: `streamA.id == streamB.id`
   This falls away since according [to the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/mediacapture-streams/#attributes):

> When a MediaStream object is created, the User Agent must generate an identifier string, and must initialize the object's id attribute to that string. A good practice is to use a UUID [rfc4122], which is 36 characters long in its canonical form. To avoid fingerprinting, implementations should use the forms in section 4.4 or 4.5 of RFC 4122 when generating UUIDs.

2. Compare the `id`'s of the [MediaStreamTracks](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStreamTrack) - same story, a UUID is generated per track.
3. Compare the tracks `labels`, which in the current Chrome contain names/identifiers of the hardware. This is very close to what I'm looking for, [*however*](https://www.w3.org/TR/mediacapture-streams/#attributes-1) (emphasis mine):

> User Agents may label audio and video sources (e.g., "Internal microphone" or "External USB Webcam"). The label attribute must return the label of the object's corresponding source, if any. **If the corresponding source has or had no label, the attribute must instead return the empty string**

Is there a different approach I could take? Should I never end up in a situation where I compare two media streams? Would you say I can trust the `label` attribute?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[groupId](https://w3c.github.io/mediacapture-main/#def-constraint-groupId) together with [kind](https://w3c.github.io/mediacapture-main/#dom-mediastreamtrack-kind) is probably the closest thing you will get. Until you get multiple mics/cams on the same device...

Comment: `groupId` by definition can be the same for two different (type) tracks. Unless I misunderstand the question, I think you want `deviceId`. Neither are implemented yet though.